# ABPersonViewController Change selector for Cancel Button on EDIT MODE

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, abpersonviewcontroller

Below is my code:

```
(init a ABPersonViewController:)

    - (id)initWithPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (self) {
            self.addressBook = ContactsGetAddressBook();
            self.displayedPerson = person;
            self.allowsEditing = YES;
            self.editing = YES;
        }
    }
```

When I touch the **Cancel button**, it not call the

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing
```

but **Done button** called.

when I touch the **cancel button**, I want to dismiss the **PersonViewController** directly, *skip the Info Interface*.

I have the desire to get the touch event for **Cancel button** (on **edit mode**).

Comment: have you set the delegate of ABPersonViewController?

Comment: yes, and it can't solve my problem.